# Careers 2.0 - A few bugs

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-norepro, jobs

I recently submitted my application to a job I saw on SO Careers 2.0 and I faced a few problems:

1. There's a bug (in Firefox and Chrome) when setting the start date of an employment position - clicking on the `<select>` elements doesn't cause them to open, you have to show the Options buttons for the drop-downs to get focus.
2. When supplying the details of some of my open-source projects I'm unable to set the Technologies tags (the `disabled` attribute is set for some reason), and in fact the Project Name field is blanked when I tab out of it.
3. When editing the Technologies tag list for a job or project (assuming problem #2 doesn't exist) I cannot add new tags once the text box is full if I'm editing it after I've saved it. If I'm filling in the box for the first time then I can supply as many tags as I want even if I fill up the box.
4. I cannot add the details of a project or application without providing a working URI for it. This means I have to provide a generic URI for internal, unreleased or obsolete applications I've developed. I also wish there was a space to provide screenshots.
5. I can't see any central way to track my existing applications. Only a "Good luck!" message on job adverts that I have applied for.
6. After submitting my application I realised I left out some further work examples that would have benefited my application - this is my fault for not proof-reading my application, but an ability to recall an application would be very useful, even if the job advertiser received my application originally but also received a recall or "ignore my application" notice. This would be of use to people who send out job applications while under the influence of alcohol too :)

Comment: Would be best if you split the [bug] and [feature-request] parts in two separate questions. They don't require the same type of answers/community feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, so it's possible some of these were fixed along the way.  In any case, this is the state of each I can devise right now.

1. No repro, clicking anywhere on the select element causes them to open.
2. No repro, I can't find a single one of your open source projects that has any of the fields set to disabled.
3. You can add more tags, it's just not very use friendly.  If you click on the one of the existing tags (not the X that deletes it) it will change that tag to text which you can edit.  If you press end at this point it will take you to the end of all the tags where you can now add new tags.  We're testing out a new solution for this on the company pages right now and once we find something that works better there, we will likely update this everywhere.
4. The entire point of your Careers profile is to show off your public artifacts on the internet.  If you don't want to include a working url, it's best to include the project details under the experience section.  I like the idea of screenshots, but that needs to be its own feature request.
5. If you click the user messages tab at the top you will be able to see all of your applications in one place.
6. We have discussed this before and declined this feature.  As soon as you apply we send an email to the employer with the contents of your cover letter, so effectively once it's sent, it's sent.  We provide a review stage in the application process for exactly this reason.